# How to select entire row in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm new in java. I have problem with selection current row. First, I've selected fifth row, and as you can see it works. But, when I want to select third row it changes selection immediately on fifth row.  Please, help me if you know. Thanks in advance.

```
         for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
               if (jtable.getValueAt(i, 1).toString().contains(string1)) {
                   table.setRowSelectionInterval(i, i);
               if (table.isRowSelected(i)) {
                  table.setValueAt(Boolean.TRUE, i, 0);
                  table.setSelectionBackground(new Color(51, 204, 255));
                  textField.selectAll();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is FIRST image when I click on checkbox on the fifth row: (And it reacts ok)

[image]

This is SECOND image when I click on checkbox on the third row: (I don't want that).

[image]

I've expected this THIRD image, instead of SECOND image:  [image]

Do you get it? Do you know how to solve this problem if you got it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it changes selection immediately on fifth row" ?

Comment: When I want to check third row, I expect to select entire third row. Instead of that, "the selector" move on fifth row

Comment: I think you should check out a basic example here: [Multiple Select Demo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/TableListSelectionDemoProject/src/events/TableListSelectionDemo.java), Hope it helps.

Comment: For me, I don't think this is basic example :) I hope that will help me.

Comment: Try posting a [mcve].

Comment: I've edited post

Comment: 1) *"I've edited post"* Why? What you posted is not a [mre]. 2) Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.